# using macros in C to convert multiple arguments into one

Tags: macros

I'm brand new to C, and I'm trying to do something like the following:

I have a function `move(int x, int y)`
i want to be able to say `move(CENTER)`

I'm trying to say "`#define CENTER x/2, y/2`"

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> `move(CENTER)`

So you want to be able to call `move` on a variable named `center`? You could use a struct:

```
struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
}

...

void move(struct point p) {
  // read from p.x and p.y
}

...

struct point center;
center.x = 20;
center.y = 20;
move(center);
```

I'm not sure what your intent was with the `#define CENTER x/2, y/2` part... Did you mean something like `#define CENTER WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2`? You can just do `center.x = WIDTH / 2` and `center.y = HEIGHT / 2`.

**edit:** If you can't re-define `move` you could try something like

```
void my_move(struct point p) {
  move(p.x, p.y);
}
```

Comment: So just to be clear, only way for me to be able to say move (center) when move takes 2 ints is to write a my_move?

Wouldn't a macro work? Or is it just "not done" per convention. .. I also don't want c programmers hating me

Comment: A macro could work, but as a rule of thumb, macros are bad practice, and you should try to avoid them when possible. The style of macro you're suggesting is rather uncommon, which makes using it even less preferable.